# Has anyone had a positive experience using Google Analytics in their native iOS app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm having a hard time finding reviews on Google Analytics for native iOS apps and I was hoping to find some programmers on here that have any experience with it.  If so, how well did it work?

Thanks so much for your thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

I've used it and it worked ok, but I wouldn't say there was a lot of information collected automatically for you.  It would have been nice to have more info about iOS versions, device types, etc.

It was a pretty dead simple API to implement though and reporting access to different sections of the app as "pages" was easy.  The analytics website itself is definitely geared towards web analytics and the mobile feels like a bit of a hack.